# Change font used by moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv, mathpazo

Using **moderncv**, is it possible to change the font? I tried to load the Palatino font with:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

with no avail.

I'm using Tex Live 2011, and I compile the tex file with `pdflatex`.

Comment: It should be possible to use a different font with `moderncv`. What happens? Do you get an error message? Does it fail to compile? Does it compile, but use computer modern? Without more information, we can't help.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too much clear. Everything goes just as if the mathpazo package isn't loaded at all (no errors, good pdf generated, but with the same default fonts used by _moderncv_).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pass the `roman` option to **moderncv**:

```
\documentclass[roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

In this way only the titles will be in a sans serif font. If you want everything in Palatino,

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}
```

Comment: Yes! It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

`moderncv` uses a sans serif font for the entire document. As far as I can tell, there is no sans serif font in `mathpazo`, so you probably want to use the normal Palatino font in that package. To do that, you need to load the package change the sans serif font. Add

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}
```

at the end of your preamble.

[image: moderncv in Palatino]

Comment: Your solution also worked correctly. And thank you for the demonstration of the result.