# Missing \endcsname inserted. An error with one of my labels in bbl

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I am getting an error:

```
line 1356: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...lyzingGeneticCircuits_fontanarrosa_2019}
line 1357: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...}{DesignAsynchronousGenetic_nguyen_2019}
```

and when I click on it I'm taken to this line of the .bbl:

```
  \keyalias{AnalyzingGeneticCircuits\_fontanarrosa\_2019a}{AnalyzingGeneticCircuits_fontanarrosa_2019}
  \keyalias{DesignAsynchronousGenetic\_nguyen\_2019a}{DesignAsynchronousGenetic_nguyen_2019}
```

I have some citations with Spanish accents (e.g.: padró). Do you think that might be the problem?

Each time I compile, I run the following `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf` . This is is the preamble for my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman
%Check: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31534/change-font-used-by-moderncv
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%% ADDED PACKAGES
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist, maxbibnames=99,backend=biber, sorting = ydnt, doi=false ,url=false, isbn=false, giveninits=true, plauthorhandling=highlight, plauthorname=Fontanarrosa, boldyear=false, date=year]{biblatex}
%backend=biber. Hay que correr Latex, despues biber, y despues LaTeX denuevo para que funcione
%publist style for making my surname *bold*
%sorting = ydnt ordena por year al reves
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{-}
%esto elimina numeracion por -
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{5pt}
%esto setea el length de el marcador
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}

\usepackage{textcomp} %Symbols, symbols, symbols
```

Comment: It looks like you have something like `ids = {AnalyzingGeneticCircuits\_fontanarrosa\_2019a},` in your entry `AnalyzingGeneticCircuits_fontanarrosa_2019`. The version with escaped underscores `AnalyzingGeneticCircuits\_fontanarrosa\_2019a` is not a valid name and will cause problems. Remove those `ids` from your `.bib` file.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. How and why are these id's produced?

Comment: I have no idea why they are in your `.bib` file if that is what you mean. If my guess as to what the `ids` field in the `.bib` file is correct, they are completely pointless.